# How do I enable in-place tablet pc input panel for non tablet PCs?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, mouse, touchscreen

Is it possible to enable the in-place tablet PC input panel on a non-tablet PC?

I have checked the "For tablet pen input, show the Input Panel icon next to the text entry area when possible" checkbox in the options of the Input Panel.
Does this not work because pen input is something different than mouse input? I do have a touch screen, but it just emulates a mouse (moving the cursor, pressing the left mouse button and such).

I can get the Input Panel to show manually by starting tabtip.exe and then event the ink works, but I cannot get it to show (itself or it's in-place icon) when I activate text input controls.

Does anyone know what's up?

Answer (score 1):

There is a little app called floattip.exe I found. Just run this and it fools the input panel into thinking you are using a tablet pen, which makes the icon appear next to text input boxes.
Works a treat for most input in Vista.
You have to start the input panel before it works, but once running it will hide when you use the cross to close it.

Answer (score 0):

Start/All Programs/Accessories/Tablet PC/ Tablet PC Input Panel